# MediBang - How can I move objects from multiplayer layers while still keeping its distance from each other?

Tags: layers, selections

Sorry if the title didn't make sense but I'll try to explain my best. Basically, I have this drawing where the yellow scribble is in layer 2 whereas the red scribble is in layer 3:
[image]

Let's say red scribble is higher than yellow scribble by *x* value. So, I want to move both of these scribbles down while still maintaining the fact that red scribble is still higher than yellow scribble *x* value. At the same time, I also want the distance between the 2 scribbles to be the same when I moved down:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

I'm terribly sorry if this doesn't make any sense. But any help would be sincerely appreaciated.

Thanks alot!

Comment: I am not familiar with the software you are using, but most graphics software can group objects/layers/images so that when moved, they move together.  You may need to check the software's documentation to find that function.

Comment: The main issue with using some of the free image editors out there, is lack of community. You really are better off asking at the web site the product is from. I've never heard of "MediBang", which doesn't mean a great deal. But if the user base is small, you may not get any answers here.

Comment: Mediabang is actually a large community. The software integrates with their platform that hosts an infinite amount of design contests.
The reason I came across it is that it is the only free software I've seen that can open Photoshop files without a problem. GIMP, for example, struggles to convert some parts of an original PSD. I'm pretty it is layer masks that won't make the transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curiosity pushed me to check what's that program - it's name sounded as those everyday power and size pills spam questions. But the software is real, working, at least now freeware and seemingly intended for painting and cartoon making for those who can draw and paint.

You can select several layers by holding shift at the same time as you click in the layers panel. Then the move tool moves all selected layers the same amount:

[image]

More preferably you can make a layer folder. All layers which are dragged to the same folder can be moved by selecting and moving the folder. Actually layer folders are the way to keep things in control when you have, say 50 or 100 layers. Layer folders can have several levels.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: NOTE: If one of the layers is invisible, the group will not move together. It seems that only the top layer in the group will be moved. This is not a very intuitive interaction.